# Can't put new SSD partitions in use

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I just tried to add new partitions of swap and boot to my laptop. However, I feel these two partitions are not in use, as they are always empty. And I can't see them showing up on Device&Location, where there are only the default root and home partitions.

[image: snippet1]
[image: snippet2]
[image: snippet3]

I am new to Ubuntu and I don't know if I am doing the right thing. Should I reinstall the entire operating system? Please help.

Comment: If you are new, why are you then adding partitions? That is not what a default installation does. It sets up everything in a single partition, ready to use.

Comment: To see what files and/or partitions that are in use for swap run `swapon` in a terminal.

Comment: @vanadium
yes, I just want to make my os more durable and well-organized. I don't feel like get my entire os running slow someday after I set up everything.

Comment: @Nmath okay.Then should I just go with the default single partition?

Comment: A separate boot partition is unnecessary and a swap partition is not very useful if you are using a SSD.  If you have 16 GB of actual RAM, it's likely that your system will rarely, if ever, use swap.  Overpartitioning does not make your system "more durable" nor does it help with organization. Use folders for organizon- not partitions.  `/boot` will be mounted in the same place regardless if it is on a separate partition and you will never need to try to find anything on your swap space. Ubuntu has been using a swap file by default for several years now.

Comment: There's no need to add any additional partitions during or after system installation.

Comment: @Nmath Got it. Thanks a lot!